# Upgrading xubuntu 17.04 to 17.10 can not connect to the internet

Tags: xubuntu, internet, 17.10

Today I upgraded xubuntu 17.04 to xubuntu 17.10. When I restarted my computer, the result was that I could not connect to the internet. But when I went to Run Windows 7 in the oracle vm virtualbox it was able to connect to the internet.
I need a lot of help right now.
please help me
Thank you

Comment: $ iwconfig
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"InHOME"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: A0:F3:C1:72:70:9E   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp4s0    no wireless extensions.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can not wait to solve the problem, because I have to contact my job, so I started using Linux Mint 18.2 instead of xubuntu because I can not find any solutions to this problem. I think that's a bug that can not be solved by Ubuntu, so I think that since I upgraded from 16.04 lts to 17.04 the same day. Keep an editable
 And I'm thankful for all the answers, which I think I will wait for a while before I go back to xubuntu again, but I'm sure Linux Mint 18.2 is not bad for me.